# Javascript apply a function for all the elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, r, svg

I have made a code that counts and sets an svg circle strokeDasharray and strokeDashoffset. It works completely fine but now I have to apply it for multiple svgs.
Here is the working code for one element:

```
<div class="progress-ring-container">
  <div class="span-container">
    <span>Users</span>
    <span>4.3</span>
  </div>

<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

```
// Circle progress bar
var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

function setProgress(percent) {
   const offset = circumference - percent / 5 * circumference;
   circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-ring")[0].getAttribute("data-percentage");
setProgress(input);
```

And here is how I tried to solve the problem:

```
// Circle progress bar
var circles = document.querySelectorAll('circle');
var circlesArr = Array.from(circles);
circlesArr.forEach(circleArray);
 

function circleArray(circle) {
    var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
    var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

    circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;
    return circumference;
}

var circumferenceFunction = circleArray();

function setProgress(percent) {
   const offset = circumferenceFunction - percent / 5 * circumferenceFunction;
   circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-ring")[0].getAttribute("data-percentage");
setProgress(input);
```

I was thinking of using something like .each() in jQuery but I still don't find the right solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is `var circumferenceFunction = circleArray();` supposed to do?

Comment: You dont need to try anything. your code works for all svgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below :

```
var circles = document.querySelectorAll('circle');
var circlesArr = Array.from(circles);



function circleArray(circle) {
  var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
  var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;
  const input = circle.closest('.progress-ring').getAttribute("data-percentage")
  setProgress(input, circle);

  function setProgress(percent, circle) {
    const offset = circumference - percent / 5 * circumference;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  }
}

circlesArr.forEach(circleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for all `svg` which class is `circle`. why you are looping over them. just try this.
here is html:

```
<div class="progress-ring-container">
  <div class="span-container">
    <span>Users</span>
    <span>4.3</span>
  </div>

<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="100" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="100" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="180" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="180" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="260" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="260" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="340" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="340" cy="29"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

and js

```
var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

function setProgress(percent) {
   const offset = circumference - percent / 5 * circumference;
   circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-ring")[0].getAttribute("data-percentage");
setProgress(input);
```

your code is working. i didnt understand. why you need do that one by one. css works for all class

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

function setProgress(percent) {
   const offset = circumference - percent / 5 * circumference;
   circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-ring")[0].getAttribute("data-percentage");
setProgress(input);
```

```html
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="29" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="100" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="100" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="180" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="180" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="260" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="260" cy="29"/>
</svg>
<svg data-percentage="4.3" class="progress-ring">
  <circle class="circle" r="25" cx="340" cy="29"/>
  <circle class="circle bg" r="25" cx="340" cy="29"/>
</svg>
</div>
```